# Detectar y eliminar listas duplicadas en array de listas en Python

Tags: python

Tengo una gran cantidad de listas dentro de un array y necesito desarrollar una forma de detectar que una lista no sea idéntica a otra.
Cada lista del array está ordenada de menor a mayor y tiene la misma cantidad de ítems.

```
    l0=[1,10,25,30,50]
    l1=[4,21,55,60,71]
    l2=[3,14,26,38,60]
    l3=[8,20,35,45,78]
    l4=[9,19,21,37,88]
    l5=[5,9,33,45,59]
    l6=[2,20,45,70,90]
    l7=[6,10,25,80,99]
    l8=[11,25,35,50,72]
    l9=[1,10,25,30,50]
    myArray=[l0,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9]
    print(myArray)
    set(myArray)
    print(myArray)
```

La verdad no estoy encontrando una solución siendo que estoy dando mis primeros pasos en python.

Según este ejemplo la lista `l0` y `l9` son iguales, así que debería descartarse una de ellas.

[image]

Comment: No puedes usar números como nombres de variables!!

Answer (score 1):

Sin tener el código no puedo darte una solución más ajustada, pero creo que lo que buscas es el método `set()`.

`set()` te devuelve un iterable con todos los elementos únicos de otro conjunto.

Una forma de comprobar que una lista de ese array no sea idéntica a otra sería crear un set de ese array y comprobar la longitud de ambos. Si el set es más pequeño significa que había un duplicado.

Otra forma sería usando el método `.index()` del iterable y capturar la excepción si no existe y usar el método `.count()` para saber si hay más de un duplicado de cada elemento del array. De esta forma matas dos pájaros de un tiro. Obtienes el índice si existe para poder "popearlo" de la lista si necesitas (siempre sería el primer elemento de los duplicados). Hay varias formas de hacerlo, más o menos complejas, pero como digo, sin el código que has intentando no te podemos dar un ejemplo más claro.

### EDIT 2

Sigo manteniendo lo de que se podría simplificar si tuvieramos el resto del código, pero corrijo mi solución por que no se puede crear un set de una lista de listas por no ser inmutable, pero la solución sigue siendo conceptualmente la misma:

```
def crearCarton():
    while(True):
        #creacion de numeros
        ??????
        #//////////////////////
        # ORDENAMOS LAS LISTAS
        carton1.sort()
        carton2.sort()
        carton3.sort()
        carton4.sort()
        carton5.sort()
        carton6.sort()

        boleto =  [carton1,carton2,carton3,carton4,carton5,carton6]
        mySet = [tuple(carton) for carton in boleto] # Necesitas crear una copia de la lista y hacerla tuplas inmutables para poder usar `set()`

        if len(boleto) == len(set(mySet)):
            return boleto
```

Y eso devuelve ya el array con los cartones únicos, porque no saldrá del bucle hasta que todos los cartones sean diferentes (que si los generas aleatoriamente ya seria mala casualidad) y te ahorras todo el resto del código que has puesto.

Comment: Disculpa pero intente pegar el codigo y no entiendo porque no me dejaba guardar. No soy muy experto en esta plataforma ya que la use muy pocas veces. Voy a tratar de nuevo.

Comment: Ya tengo solucionado el tema y estoy seguro que hay mejores formas de crearlo ya q recien estoy comenzando con python. Pero creo tenerlo resuelto y no creo que todo el codigo sea necesario si la consulta es solo determinar si hay listas duplicadas en un array de listas.

Comment: Las normas del sitio piden en la medida de lo posible añadir un código mínimamente reproducible, no es capricho mío. Me gustaría pedirle por favor que si lo ha solucionado con mis indicaciones seleccione mi respuesta como aceptada o si por el contrario lo has resuelto de otra manera añadir una respuesta nueva con tu solución para que todo el mundo se beneficie. Un saludo

Comment: Aún no soluciono mi problema y voy a tratar de simplificar todo con u ncode reducido. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Una solución elemental es generar una lista a partir de la original

```
lista1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
lista2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
lista3 = [-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
lista4 = [-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

lista_de_listas = [lista1, lista2, lista1, lista3, lista4, lista1, lista3]
nueva_lista = []
```

Tenemos una lista_de_listas con repeticiones varias y una nueva_lista vacía. A continuación usaremos un `for` para tomar cada elemento y ver si está en la nueva_lista. Si no está, lo agregamos a la nueva lista. En otro caso, lo descartamos

```
for lista in lista_de_listas:
  if lista not in nueva_lista:
    nueva_lista.append(lista)
```

Al terminar el ciclo, sólo nos queda reemplazar la lista original con la nueva versíón:

```
lista_de_listas = nueva_lista
print(lista_de_listas)
```

produce:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

#### Uso de memoria

A primera vista parece un derroche crear una nueva lista a partir de la primera.

La verdad es que las operaciones con listas no duplican sus contenidos. En el ejemplo expuesto, cada una de las lista1, lista2, ... sólo está presente una vez en memoria.

Las lista en si son una colección de punteros (indices) que finalmente llevan al elemento en si. Cada puntero o indices ocupa unos pocos bytes, sin importar el tamaño del elemento mismo.

Comment: pero es que nadie entiende mi planteo parece. Yo se como generar las listas solo necesito saber como checar eficientemente q una lista no este duplicada .

Answer (score 1):

Lo que entiendo de tu pregunta es:

> solo necesito saber como checar eficientemente q una lista no este
> duplicada

Si entendemos la duplicidad como dos o más listas con los mismos elementos, entonces una forma posibles es mediante comprensión de listas:

```
array_status = [(lista, lista in [lista2 for i2, lista2 in enumerate(myArray) if i2 != i]) for i,lista in enumerate(myArray)]
```

Esto generará un nuevo array con tuplas dónde el primer elemento es la sublista y el segundo un valor lógico que nos informa si la misma está repetida o no.
Para  saber finalmente cuales son las repetidas:

```
print([lista for lista, repetida in array_status if repetida])
```

Answer (score -1):

Ya encontre la solucion aca!
Gracias a los que intentaron apoyarme.

[Eliminar lista duplicada de Array de Listas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783326/how-to-make-a-set-of-lists)

Comment: Explica brevemente el contenido del enlace que proporcionas y cómo es que te ha sido útil: ten en cuenta que puede que el contenido no esté disponible más adelante, volviendo inválida esta respuesta. Lee [answer]. _La respuesta debe ser útil no solo para ti_.

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.